multiple charts with amcharts 5
I'm developing a web application for a college project, in which I'm using the amcharts library to generate some graphs, however, I can only generate one graph in div's with the id "chartdiv", and this prevents me from generating more than one graph on the same page, does anyone have any idea what the error could be?
function createChart(id, data) {
    const root = am5.Root.new(id);
    root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

    const chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
        layout: root.verticalLayout
    }));

    const series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
        valueField: "value",
        categoryField: "category"
    }));

    series.slices.template.setAll({
        fillOpacity: 1,
        stroke: am5.color(0x000000),
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    series.get("colors").set("colors", [
        am5.color(0xa02a89),
        am5.color(0x6a1c71),
    ]);
    series.slices.template.set("toggleKey", "none");
    series.ticks.template.set("visible", false);
    series.labels.template.set("forceHidden", true);

    series.data.setAll(data);

    series.appear(1000, 100);
}


dataGraphic = [
            {value: "{{ vit }}", category: "Vitórias"}, 
            {value: "{{ qtd - vit }}", category: "Derrotas"}
        ];

am5.ready(createChart("chartdiv", dataGraphic));

I changed the id's in the function call and it still didn't work

Are you overwriting the previous variables data when you try adding a second chart? In your code it looks like only one chart is being instantiated, am I incorrect? Are you calling the function over again using a different element param? Can you post your code that shows an attempt at creating multiple charts? Its def possible... https://jsfiddle.net/p2wybjrt/

Simply create two different chart DIVs (e.g. <div id="chartdiv"></div> and <div id="chartdiv2"></div>) and then do what you want by using two separate am5.ready()

wrap your chart creating function call to a function like this
am5.ready(function() {
    var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
});

read more about this in the docs about root element
Also provide proper values ( with supported types )
eg: provide number as value
          dataGraphic = [
                  {value: 8, category: "Vitórias"},
                  {value: 12, category: "Derrotas"}
              ];



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      #chartdiv {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
      }

      #chartdiv2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    <div id="chartdiv2"></div>

      <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

    <script>

          //var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
          //var root2 = am5.Root.new("chartdiv2");
          

          function createChart(id, data) {
          const root = am5.Root.new(id);
          root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

          const chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
              layout: root.verticalLayout
          }));

          const series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
              valueField: "value",
              categoryField: "category"
          }));

          series.slices.template.setAll({
              fillOpacity: 1,
              stroke: am5.color(0x000000),
              strokeWidth: 1
          });

          series.get("colors").set("colors", [
              am5.color(0xa02a89),
              am5.color(0x6a1c71),
          ]);
          series.slices.template.set("toggleKey", "none");
          series.ticks.template.set("visible", false);
          // series.labels.template.set("forceHidden", true);

          series.data.setAll(data);

          series.appear(1000, 100);
      }


      dataGraphic = [
                  {value: 8, category: "Vitórias"},
                  {value: 12, category: "Derrotas"}
              ];

      am5.ready(function(){
        createChart("chartdiv", dataGraphic)
      });
            am5.ready(function(){
        createChart("chartdiv2", dataGraphic)
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



